# PYTHON - How do I sort and round the values of a dictionary but keep them assigned to the same key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of tuples.

```
AddRatio=0.2
SubRatio=0.25
MultiRatio=0.2
DiviRatio=0.2
MoneyRatio=0.15

num_dict = {"add": 10*AddRatio, "sub": 10*SubRatio, "multi": 10*MultiRatio, 
            "divi": 10*DiviRatio, "money": 10*MoneyRatio}
```

Firstly, I need to remove .0 from any of the numbers for sorting later. E.g. 2.0 would become 2 and 3.5 would remain as 3.5

With help, I got this line to do this:

```
num_dict = {k: int(v) if v == int(v) else v for k, v in num_dict.items()}
```

I then run a check for floats in the dictionary if there are any:

```
keys=["add", "sub", "multi", "divi", "money"]

for i in range(len(num_dict)):
    if type(num_dict[keys[i]]) is float:
        sortRound()
        break
```

Leading into the function sortRound() which as the name suggests, sorts the values and then rounds them.

So far, I have this:

```
def sortRound():
    global num_add_qs, num_sub_qs, num_multi_qs, num_divi_qs, num_money_qs
    global num_dict, keys

    def bubbleSort(num_dict):
        for passnum in range(len(num_dict)-1,0,-1):
            for i in range(passnum):
                if num_dict[keys[i]]>num_dict[keys[i+1]]:
                    temp = num_dict[keys[i]]
                    num_dict[keys[i]] = num_dict[keys[i+1]]
                    num_dict[keys[i+1]] = temp

    bubbleSort(num_dict)

    for i in range(0, len(num_dict)):
        j=len(num_dict)-1
        if isinstance(num_dict[keys[i]], int):
            i=i+1
        elif isinstance(num_dict[keys[i]], float):
            num_dict[keys[i]] = math.ceil(num_dict[keys[i]])
            while isinstance(num_dict[keys[j]], int):
                j=j-1
            if isinstance(num_dict[keys[j]], float):
                num_dict[keys[j]]=int(num_dict[keys[j]])
```

Now the above code does work as intended in terms of sorting and rounding the numbers as far as I can see. The issue is that they are assigned to the wrong variable.

If ratios were as followed:

```
AddRatio=0.05
SubRatio=0.2
MultiRatio=0.2
DiviRatio=0.2
MoneyRatio=0.35
```

The dictionary would end up as follows:

```
{'add': 1, 'sub': 2, 'multi': 2, 'divi': 2, 'money': 3}
```

which is what I want. However if the ratios are as follows:

```
AddRatio=0.2
SubRatio=0.05
MultiRatio=0.2
DiviRatio=0.2
MoneyRatio=0.35
```

The result is the same as above when my intention is for it to be as follows:

```
{'add': 2, 'sub': 1, 'multi': 2, 'divi': 2, 'money': 3}
```

When sorted, the first half of floats should be rounded up regardless and the second half should be rounded down regardless.
E.g.

```
1.5, 2, 3, 4.5, 5
```

results in

```
2, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

In short, how do I sort and round the values of a dictionary but keep them assigned to the same key?
I think the issue lies within the bubble sort but I'm not sure how to correct it and after multiple attempts am struggling to see what else I can try.

EDIT

The dictionary itself doesn't need to be ordered necessarily as I know this isn't possible.
The values need to be sorted and rounded and then assigned back to the key they came from if that makes sense.

Comment: You want to swap keys and values? `dict`s have no order, so sorting won't do anything. Maybe convert it to a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought there would be a way to somehow sort the values and then reassign them back to the key they came from.

Solved using list of tuples as suggested by internet_user

> You want to swap keys and values? dicts have no order, so sorting won't do >anything. Maybe convert it to a list of tuples – internet_user

```
AddRatio=0.2
SubRatio=0.05
MultiRatio=0.2
DiviRatio=0.2
MoneyRatio=0.35

num_list = [["add", 10*AddRatio], ["sub", 10*SubRatio], ["multi", 10*MultiRatio], \
            ["divi", 10*DiviRatio], ["money", 10*MoneyRatio]]

#Removes .0 if required (2.0 --> 2, 3.5 --> 3.5)
#This means that the rounding works later on
for i in range(0, len(num_list)):
    num_list[i][1]=str(num_list[i][1])
    if num_list[i][1][2] == "0":
        num_list[i][1]=num_list[i][1][:1]
        num_list[i][1]=int(num_list[i][1])
    else:
        (num_list[i][1])=float(num_list[i][1])

num_list = sorted(num_list, key=lambda tup: tup[1])

def sortRound():
    global num_list 

    for i in range(0, len(num_list)):
        j=len(num_list)-1
        if isinstance(num_list[i][1], int):
            i=i+1
        elif isinstance(num_list[i][1], float):
            num_list[i][1] = math.ceil(num_list[i][1])
            while isinstance(num_list[j][1], int):
                j=j-1
            if isinstance(num_list[j][1], float):
                num_list[j][1]=int(num_list[j][1])

for i in range(len(num_list)):
    if type(num_list[i][1]) is float:
        sortRound()
        break
```

bubbleSort is no longer needed either. It is replaced by

```
num_list = sorted(num_list, key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Python dictionaries are not ordered, so sorting them is meaningless.  Use an ordered type like a NamedTuple or OrderedDict.

Comment: I need the values to be sorted and rounded and then to be assigned back to the dictionary key they came from if that's possible.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about what you mean by sorted.  If you need the dictionary sorted (i.e. in order of keys or values), that just isn't possible with a standard python dict because they're unordered by definition.  You'll need to use an ordered data type.

You can edit the values (e.g. round them) with no problem: dict['key'] = round(dict['key'])

Comment: I want to take the value from the dictionary. Let's say 0.5, 2, 1, 2.5, 3. Sort them into ascending order so 0.5, 1, 2, 2.5, 3. Then round the first half of floats (0.5) up regardless and second half of floats (2.5) down regardless. But I need them to remain assigned to the same key. The above code does this, but assigns values to a different key which isn't what I want.

Comment: Say add-0.5, sub=2, multi=1, divi=2.5 and money=3. After being sorted and rounded and such, the result SHOULD be add=1, sub=2, multi=1, divi=2 and money=3. The code above would result in add=1, sub=1, multi=2, divi=2 and money=3.

Comment: That's because when you do num_dict[keys[i]] = num_dict[keys[i+1]] you are assigning the value to a different key.  Once again, you cannot sort a Python dict. If you want to sort, you need to use a different data structure.

Comment: Python dictionaries are ordered as of version 3.6

Comment: That appears to be an implementation detail in CPython rather than part of the language definition. Do you have some info to the contrary?